# SonarQube plugins for cucumber tests, selenium tests and AEM

Tags: java, selenium, sonarqube, cucumber, aem

What **plugins do we need to install on SonarQube** for the following to be integrated? (also the code changes that need to be made)
1) Selenium test integration
2) Cucumber test integration
3) AEM Integration

I am trying to investigate if Java plugin can cover some of these tests but, so far I found nothing.

Any help is appretiated.

Comment: What is exactly your need? Get the quality of the tests written in Gherkin? Get the code coverage by your Cucumber integration tests?

Comment: I want the code coverage displayed on Sonar. So I am looking for the right plugin.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube can import code coverage reports (one for unit tests and one for integration tests). Thus, you need to compute code coverage on your side (with JaCoCo for example). Then tell SonarQube to process this report. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests+for+Java+Project